# Using Gulp + BrowserSync + Connect PHP for Multiple Projects

Tags: javascript, php, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-connect-php

I've put together a boilerplate gulp setup for myself when setting up a new webapp project and I'm having some trouble with using BrowserSync, and Connect-PHP in tandem.

Here's are my tasks for spinning up the server and starting BS:

```
gulp.task('php', function() {
    php.server({base: 'app', port: 8030, keepalive: true});
})

gulp.task('browserSync',['php'], function(){
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: '127.0.0.1:8030',
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
})
```

The problem is that every time I set up a new project, I have to change the port for the php server and proxy url to a new, previously unused one.

Is there a way I can avoid having to choose a new port number each time?

For further reference, it appears this question was asked before but not answered here: [Can't use gulp (with gulp-connect-php and gulp-browser-sync) with multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574277/cant-use-gulp-with-gulp-connect-php-and-gulp-browser-sync-with-multiple-proje#)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?